# Can't start with program. Simple task with Scanner in Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

My Program doesn't want to run. I don't know, where is the problem.

My task is following:
Write a program which asks the user, by means of an object of type Scanner, to enter his/her height (in meters, as double), then the weight (in kilograms, also as a double). Then the program displays in a message box `(JOptionPane.showMessageDialog)` his/her BMI coefficient (body mass index) defined as the weight in kilograms divided by the square of height in meters - this number should come out close to 20.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Write your height, then press ENTER");
    java.util.Scanner in = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    double x = in.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Write your weight, then press ENTER");
    java.util.Scanner in2 = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    double y = in.nextDouble();

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog((double)("Your BMI is"+y:(x*x)));
}
```

I'm very very beginner. Can you please explain me my mistakes?

Comment: My version is jdk 10.0.2

Comment: Please remove the JavaScript tag in your question . Your question relates to Java not JavaScript

Comment: It would be great if you mention the Exception you are getting when you are trying to run this program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be 2 mistakes in your answer.

1) You need to use `/` to divide instead of `:`

2) You are trying to typecast `String` message to `double`.

Refer the below corrected code -

```
double bodyMass = y/(x*x);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog("Your BMI is"+bodyMass);
```

Comment: What should I use instead of String? Because program can't see JOptionPane.showMessageDialog
Or maybe the reason is  that I'm using Notepad ++?

Comment: You should use String only. But you can’t typecast String characters to double. I didn’t get what you mean by your second sentence. Hope you are using proper import statements for JOptionPane. Are you still getting any CompileTimeException or RuntimeException? If yes, please share it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the last line:

> "Your BMI is"+y:(x*x)

If you want to divide something you need to use the'/' operator.
Ialso think that you need brackets:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog((double)("Your BMI is"+(y/(x*x))));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not cast double to any string. Your code does that which is an **ERROR**

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog("Your BMI is"+y/(x*x));
```

Notice that above code I've removed that **double** cast. And you don't even need any double cast because the result will always going to be **double**.